# How to Populate the numbers between a range of two values using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table having 2 columns like Minvalue and Maxvalue and values as below

```
Minvalue  |   Maxvalue
   5      |     12
```

Wanted to write a SQL query to display the sequence of the numbers between the minvalue and maxvalue range as below

```
Output

Values
--------
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`CONNECT BY LEVEL` clause can be used for this. It will generate a list starting by LEVEL = 1. `LEVEL BETWEEN x and y` doesn't work but workarounds are:

1. Loop through the gap (between 5 and 12) and add the starting value to each of the entries. You'll need to adjust for LEVEL starting at 1 not 0.

```
SELECT level + 4 FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8
```

2. Use a CTE

```
WITH min_max(min_val, max_val) AS
(SELECT 5 , 12 FROM DUAL)
SELECT LEVEL + min_val - 1 
  FROM min_max CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (max_val - min_val) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Connect by depending on parameters

```
with prms as (
  select 5 minval, 12 maxval from dual
)
select prms.minval + rownum - 1
from prms connect by prms.minval + rownum - 1 <= prms.maxval
```